# Fechar conexão com banco de dados c#

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

Estou fazendo um sistema de login e recebo a mensagem de sql exception quando tento criar nova conta no banco de dados:

```
MySqlCommand usuaExiste = new MySqlCommand(
    "SELECT * FROM contas WHERE nome = '"+textBox1.Text+"'", bdConn);
bool resultado = usuaExiste.ExecuteReader().HasRows;
if (resultado == true || textBox2.Text == null || textBox2.Text.Length < 4)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Por favor, certifique se sua senha não é muito curta, seu usuário já é existente ou ele é muito curto.");
}
else
{
    try
    {
        MySqlCommand criar = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO contas (nome, senha) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')", bdConn);
        criar.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
        criar.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Conta Criada com sucesso!");
        bdConn.Close();
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Erro ao criar a conta, informe isto ao desenvolvedor! \r\n "+ ex);
    }
}
```

Ocorre o seguinte erro:

[image: erro]

Comment: Tente comentar a linha `criar.BeginExecuteNonQuery();` ou chamar `usuaExiste.Dispose();` depois que você preenche `resultado`.

Answer (score 12):

Nesta linha:

```
bool resultado = usuaExiste.ExecuteReader().HasRows;
```

Você está criando um `Data Reader`. Um `Data Reader` é um objeto que você usa para fazer leituras rápidas do resultado de uma consulta. Enquanto você tiver um Data Reader aberto numa conexão, você não deve executar comandos nela. Você deve fechar o Data Reader antes de executar os comandos, exatamente como a mensagem de erro indica.

Note que o `Data Reader` é o retorno do método `ExecuteReader`. Você não está segurando esse `Data Reader` em uma variável, e dessa forma não terá como fechá-lo. Sugiro fazer algo mais parecido com:

```
bool resultado;
using (var dataReader = usuaExiste.ExecuteReader()) {
    resultado = dataReader.HasRows();
} // o "using" garantirá o fechamento do Data Reader aqui
```

Note que há outras formas de se saber se uma determinada consulta tem resultados, que podem eliminar a necessidade do uso de um `Data Reader`. Aparentemente você só utiliza o `Data Reader` para saber se determinada consulta traz resultados. O método `ExecuteScalar` do objeto de comando retorna o valor da célula na primeira coluna e primeira coluna do resultado. Se você fizer um `SELECT COUNT` ou algo do tipo, você pode usar o método `ExecuteScalar` e dispensar o `Data Reader`.

Answer (score 4):

Consigo ver alguns problemas com o seu código.

Você deveria usar blocos `using` para os objetos que são `IDisposable`:

- MySqlConnection
- MySqlCommand

Assim:

- `using (var bdConn = new MySqlConnection(conexao))`
- `using (var command = new MySqlCommand("... SQL aqui ...", bdConn))`

Além disso, o método `BeginExecuteNonQuery` é a versão assíncrona do método `ExecuteNonQuery`, portanto não há necessidade de chamar ambos os métodos.

Chame apenas o método `ExecuteNonQuery` já que a intenção é esperar pelo resultado e executar algo logo em seguida de forma síncrona.

E para melhorar na performance, faça validações da interface UI, antes das verificações no banco de dados.

No final, o seu código deveria ficar mais ou menos assim (coloquei alguns comentários para indicar o que eu fiz)

```
using (var bdConn = new MySqlConnection(conexao)) // o bloco using garante que o recurso
                                                  // será libarado ao sair do bloco
                                                  // de código
{
    try
    {
        bdConn.Open();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Impossível conectar ao banco de dados, ligue o wamp server!");
    }

    if (textBox2.Text != null && textBox2.Text.Length >= 4) // fazer validações de
                                                            // interface (UI), antes das
                                                            // verificações no banco
    {
        bool resultado;
        using (var usuaExiste = new MySqlCommand(
            "SELECT * FROM contas WHERE nome = '" + textBox1.Text + "'",
            bdConn)) // using do primeiro objeto MySqlCommand
                     // o que garante que será chamado o respectivo método Dispose()
        {
            resultado = usuaExiste.ExecuteReader().HasRows;
        }

        if (!resultado)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var criar =
                    new MySqlCommand(
                        "INSERT INTO contas (nome, senha) VALUES ('"
                        + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text +
                        "')", bdConn)) // using do segundo objeto MySqlCommand
                                       // garantindo a chamada ao Dispose()
                {
                    criar.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Conta Criada com sucesso!");

                    bdConn.Close(); // NOTA: o Close não é realmente necessário,
                                    // uma vez que estamos colocando os devidos
                                    // using nas variáveis IDisposable
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                    "Erro ao criar a conta, informe isto ao desenvolvedor! \r\n "
                    + ex);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
            "Por favor, certifique se sua senha não é muito curta, "
            + "seu usuário já é existente ou ele é muito curto.");
    }
}
```

**Uma recomendação valiosa**

Você não deveria acoplar tanto o código de controle com o de acesso a dados. Seria interessante se você separasse o código de controle, e de dados (e também da parte de UI), pois futuramente, se você quiser mudar o seu banco de MySql para SQL Server ou Oracle por exemplo, você vai ter problemas para achar e corrigir todos os pontos no seu código.

Comment: Código está com a explicação clara e objetiva, muito bom.